# Find which version of Capistrano is running

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, capistrano

I'm on a shared application environment and there's several ruby versions and gemsets installed (managed via RVM). I need to validate both the Capistrano gem version and ruby version on my deploy since, for example, there's incompatibilities with the 2.14.1 version of Capistrano and ree-1.8.7.

Is there any simple or even hacky way of doing this? I'm executing the call `cap _2.13.5_ production deploy` to deploy, but I wanted to quit execution with a message back to user if the environment is not correctly set. Seems overkill, but it's a client requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking what version of capistrano will run
when you run capistrano, then run "cap -v":

```
Capistrano Version: 3.10.0 (Rake Version: 12.3.0)
```

Comment: I needed cap -V (uppercase v)

Comment: For me, they give the same output:  $ cap -v
Capistrano Version: 3.10.1 (Rake Version: 12.3.0)
$ cap -V
Capistrano Version: 3.10.1 (Rake Version: 12.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

add `capistrano` to `Gemfile` and execute using `bundle exec cap production deploy`

as for `production` - put your server configuration into the `production` task/stage and capistrano will fail to deploy because o the missing server.